# Solve the following equation if x, y and z are prime numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

$x$, $y$ and $z$ are prime numbers. Solve the following equation:
$$105 (x + y + z) = xyz$$

Knowing that
$$105 = 3 × 5 × 7$$
it seems that there's no solution for this equation considering that $xyz$ has to be divisible by 3, 5 and 7 and the only prime numbers divisible by 3, 5 and 7 are 3, 5 and 7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you consider numbers like $-7$ primes?

Comment: Related? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920034/sum-of-5-primes-is-105-times-less-than-their-product

Comment: I don't.  Only positive numbers greater than 1.

Comment: Your equation has many integer solutions, for example 
$$(x,y,z)=(-18,-15,-21),(9,-40,7),(18,15,21)$$ but your reasoning about the impossibility of prime solutions is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, let $\Omega(x)$ be the number of divisors of $x$ that can be written as $p^i$ where $p$ is a prime number and $i\geqslant 1$. Then if there is a solution for your equation, we have $\Omega(xyz)=\Omega(105(x+y+z))$, that is to say $3=3+\Omega(x+y+z)$ and thus $\Omega(x+y+z)=0$ which leads to the contradiction $x+y+z=1$. You can also, with your argument $105|xyz$, say that $\{x,y,z\}=\{3,5,7\}$ and thus $x+y+z=1$.